# Overriden method initialize does not recognize variable value change when called

Tags: java, javafx, initializer

I'm working on a MVC project and have the following issue:

In a view called *CentralLayout* is the following code:

```
EventView e = new EventView();
gridSchedule.add(e.createView(5), 1, 1, 1, 5);
```

where *createView* method is defined in the following interface:

```
public interface Creatable {
public Node createView();
public Node createView(int eventDuration);
```

}

*EventView* is implemented as:

```
public class EventView extends BaseViewController implements Initializable, Creatable {


private int PANE_HEIGHT = 10;
final int PANE_WIDTH = 99;

@FXML
private Label lblObjectOne;

@FXML
private Label lblObjectTwo;

@FXML
private Pane eventPane;

@Override
public Node createView() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Node createView(int eventDuration) {
    PANE_HEIGHT = eventDuration * 20;
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("eventView.fxml"));
    Parent root = null;
    try {
        root = fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return root;
}


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

System.out.println(PANE_HEIGHT);

    eventPane.setMaxHeight(PANE_HEIGHT);
    eventPane.setMaxWidth(PANE_WIDTH);

    lblObjectOne.setText("test");
    lblObjectTwo.setText("test");
}
}
```

NOTE: I've created eventPane in SceneBuilder and its properties are defined in eventView.fxml file.

The problem is that the final, drawn, height of eventPane is equals to 10, and not 100. In console value 10 is printed as a PANE_HEIGHT value.

Can anyone tell me, why PANE_HEIGHT haven't changed when *initialize* is called, when I first called the the createView method on object *e* and passed the value that multiplied PANE_HEIGHT variable? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a **new** controller when you use the 'FXMLLoader'. To use the one already created you have to use the [`setController`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setController-java.lang.Object-) method of the `FXMLLoader` before loading the fxml file to use a controller instance you created yourself:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("eventView.fxml"));
Parent root = null;
fxmlLoader.setController(this);
try {
    root = fxmlLoader.load();
```

Comment: Wow that was quick. Thanks a ton mate! Also I needed to make sure that the .fxml file does not have fx:controller set, because I run into "Controller value already specified."

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not re-using the same `EventView` instance (`e`) when you call `initialize()`. Only the `EventView` instance you used to call `createView()` will have the expected value for `PANE_HEIGHT`.